# Cannot debug Delphi process because of UAC

Tags: delphi, debugging, windows-7, uac

I found interesting problem with Win7/X64 machine.

For this time I haven't got problem with Delphi 6 and UAC.
The exes are working in their's place, so I can use Delphi debugger with them.

But today I got error on run the project: "Unable to create process. For this operation you need higher user level".

How can I prevent this side-effect?
What causes this?
I don't understand why the older projects are running fine, but this new isn't...

Thanks for every idea, link, information!

---

Additional info:
Normally I using the Delphi 6 IDE with normal starting (without SysAdmin rigths).
So it is never asking me with "really?" kind UAC questions.
And every of the older projects are usable with Delphi 6 - I can build, run, debug everything.
This problem happened with only this project, so I try to find the differences if possible to solve the problem.
I using normal directory ("c:\dev\anyproject"), others are using "c:\dev\otherproject1..2..n").

Comment: I think you need to give us some clues. Does the executable request elevation when started normally? That is when you start it without a debugger.

Comment: Maybe the project is located in a folder which requires elevation to write. So check the path where is located the project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing Apps with Administrator Rights in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108112/developing-apps-with-administrator-rights-in-delphi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your application request elevation when started from Windows Explorer?
Does it have a manifest?

The name of the exe, like `setup.exe`, could also trigger elevation. See an outline of the [Installer detection technology](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996230/572834).

Non-elevated process can't debug elevated process.
If your application requires elevation at the start, then you would need to run the IDE elevated to be able to debug it.

Comment: Yes, this application prompts for admin rights when I try to start it from Total Commander/Explorer. But I don't know why? What is the difference between my other applications, and this application that cause the elevation? Can you help me in this question, what I need to find?

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I got it. The problem the my application name containing "updater" substring in it's name! Thanks, you helped me lot!!! ;-)

Comment: If your updater does not need to elevate, [create and embed an application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) with `level="asInvoker"`.

Comment: @durumdara UAC was introduced with Vista, almost 6 years ago now. You should not be building manifest free applications today.

Answer (score 1):

Starting your IDE as an administrator should solve the problem (option in the context menu).
If not, you could always disable UAC while developing.

Comment: But don't disable UAC while testing: otherwise you may miss problems that your end-users will encounter when using your application.

Comment: That will allow you to debug, but it hardly "solves the problem". Now the problem is why the app requires admin rights when the developer doesn't expect it to.

Answer (score -1):

There is a number of limitations that needs administrator's rights.
For example: you cannot write data directly into `program files` directory.